# Dockable Electron windows

Tags: electron

was just wondering if anybody knows if its possible to open a new child browserWindow in Electron and make it dockable to the parent window similar to DevTools window. Would be great to have the option to dock a child window to top, bottom, left and right side of the parent and even detach it.

Thanks!

Dockoptions DevTools:

[image: Dockoptions DevTools]

Comment: Hi, same question. Did you manage to implement this behavior somehow? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! I ended up modifying this plugin https://golden-layout.com/ It has most of the behavior I needed out of the box but I modified it so that when you undock the window it creates a new child process in electron with a new window and opens up the content there.

Comment: @HalvorMjoen do you have live example on www?